# Editable table dropdown issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, select, dropdown

First of all I am very Junior about frontend developer and using the stackoverflow. I am editing a table with dropdown. But if I click all of the edit buttons it returns me last select in all dropdowns. [It is a table that I want to edit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obmh8.png)

[And this is while I select all of the edit buttons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzNpC.png)

```js
       function editBtn(event) {

                        var editTr = event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;


     var al = $(editTr).find(".companyValue0")
                             var valName = $(editTr).find(".companyValue1")
                                var valMail = $(editTr).find(".companyValue2")
                             valSelect = al.text()
                             value01 = valName.text();
                             value02 = valMail.text();
            //For remove and add active class



 //
                              var select = `<select class="form-control" id="selectOption">
</select>`
                            var inputName = `<input class="form-control" value="${value01}" />`
                            var inputMail = `<input class="form-control" value="${value02}" />`

                            valName.html(inputName)
                            valMail.html(inputMail)


                        console.log("select",select)
                                al.html(select);
 //
                           var departmentSelect = document.querySelectorAll("#selectOption")
                            console.log("depart", departmentSelect)
                                departmentSelect.forEach((item) => {
                                    ajaxBrand(item,valSelect)
                                })

                              setButtonsEdit(event)










                       }





                    function ajaxBrand(opt,value) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '{{ path('brand_selection') }}',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: {
                                name: name,
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                                console.log("data", data)
                               var brandName = data.brands

                                for(let i = 0 ; i<= brandName.length-1 ; i++) {


                                        opt.innerHTML += `
<option value="${brandName[i].id}">${brandName[i].name}</option> `


                                }




                            },
                            error: function (response) {


                                return false;


                            }


                        })
                    }
```

I hope you guys can help me.

```html
                    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class=" dash-social table-content table-align">
                            <table id="table-list" class=" table  table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; width: 100%;">


                                <thead class="thead-light">
                                <tr>

                                    <th>Firma</th>
                                    <th>Mağaza İsmi</th>
                                    <th>E-posta</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>

                                <!--end tr-->
                                </thead>

                                <tbody id="department-list">
                                 {% for dealer in dealers %}
                                    <tr data-id="{{ dealer.id }}" id="{{ dealer.brand.id }}">
                                        <td class="companyValue0">{{ dealer.brand.name }}</td>
                                        <td class="companyValue1">{{ dealer.name }}</td>
                                        <td class="companyValue2">{{ dealer.mail }}</td>
                                        <td name="buttons">
                                        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                                        <button id="bEdit" type="button" class=" btn-sm btn-success shadow mr-1"
                                        onclick="editBtn(event)"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                                         <button id="bElim" type="button" class=" btn-sm btn-danger shadow" onclick="deleteBtn(event)">
                                         <i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
                                          <button id="bAcep" type="button" class=" btn-sm btn-primary shadow mr-1" style="display:none;" onclick="acceptBtn(event)">
                                          <i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
                                           <button id="bCanc" type="button" class=" btn-sm btn-info shadow" style="display:none;" onclick="cancelBtn(event)">
                                           <i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
                                            </div>
                                            </td>
                                    </tr>
                                {% endfor %}

                                <!--end tr-->
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary shadow" id="add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#companyModal"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Yeni Satır Ekle</button>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <!--end card-body-->
              </div>
              <!--end card-->
            </div>
            <!--end col-->
          </div>
          <!--end row-->
```

Comment: Please share your `html` code where you edit

Comment: I added it now.

Comment: May be I understand your problem. When you click `editBtn` this function you get the last value of for loop. Am I right?

Comment: Yes yes that is my problem.

Comment: Tell me what is the vlaue of `event ` in `editBtn`? like pass id or something